# Concatenating Wufoo API results

Tags: php, api, concatenation, wufoo

I'm working with the [Wufoo](http://wufoo.com) api ([https://{subdomain}.wufoo.com/api/v3/forms/{formIdentifier}/entries.{xml|json}](http://www.wufoo.com/docs/api/v3/entries/get/)) trying to get all of my entries, currently around 150, as one php array. Wufoo limits the number of entries returned to 100. So now I have two php arrays that I would like to concatenate/combine into a single array.

**The Code so far:**

```
$api_uri_1 = "https://example.wufoo.com/api/v3/forms/example-form/entries.json?pageStart=0&pageSize=100";
$api_uri_2 = "https://example.wufoo.com/api/v3/forms/example-form/entries.json?pageStart=1&pageSize=100";

function wufoo_api($api_uri) {
  $curl = curl_init($api_uri);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'WUFOO-API-KEY-HERE:password');
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Wufoo Sample Code');
  $response = curl_exec($curl);
  $resultStatus = curl_getinfo($curl);

  if ($resultStatus['http_code'] == 200) {
      $results = json_decode($response, true);
      return $results;
  } else {
      $results = 'Call Failed '.print_r($resultStatus);
      return $results;
  }
}

$result1 = wufoo_api($api_uri_1);
$result2 = wufoo_api($api_uri_2);
```

**What I've tried and hasn't worked**

```
$all_results = array_merge($result1, $result2);
```

and something like this

```
$all_results = $result1;
$all_results += $result2;
```

**How can I concatenate/combine result1 and result2**

Thanks in advance for any help

**Updated: What worked**

Thanks to [Ben](https://stackoverflow.com/users/192705/ben) I realized I needed to use an array key to target the parts of the array I needed.

```
$all_results = array_merge($result1['Entries'],$result2['Entries']);
```

Comment: See the comments in my answer below, I don't think your update makes sense..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result from json_decode will contain the root element (Entries according to the api).

You would access the array of entries through $result1['Entries'], so to concatenate the entries, you'd need to do something like:

```
$all_results = array_merge($result1['Entries'],$result2['Entries']);
```

or

```
$all_results = $result1['Entries'];
$all_results += $result2['Entries'];
```

---

also for the fail case, it should be

```
$results = 'Call Failed '.print_r($resultStatus,true);
```

(otherwise, you're outputting the result of print_r rather than returning it)

Comment: Thanks Ben! The **key** I needed was appeding `['Entries']` to my variable. What ended up working was `array_push($result1['Entries'], $result2['Entries'][0]);` Thanks again!

Comment: @michaelespinosa `array_push($result1['Entries'], $result2['Entries'][0])` will only append the _first_ entry in $result2 onto $result1's entries.. that doesn't sound like what you want to do